# django pass extra arguments to filterset_class

Tags: python, django

I am using [django-filter](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter). I have filter class:

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    def __init__(self, attribute=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProductFilter, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        #do stuff with attribute
```

and my views:

```
from django_filters.views import FilterView
class ProductListView(FilterView):
        model = Product
        ....
        filterset_class = ProductFilter
```

How can i pass arguments to `ProductFilter` `__init__` function? `filterset_class = ProductFilter(attribute='width')` doesn't work.

Comment: Is attribute value is always width? if it changes where do you get this value from ? ex:like URL params

Comment: No, it's just an example. I need that value to get from cms page, which is in request.current_page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try overriding the [`get_filterset_kwargs`](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/df374f1b22c1dfefac29e1d434b84d9e23dd6fef/django_filters/views.py#L35) method:

```
class ProductListView(FilterView):
    model = Product
    ...
    filterset_class = ProductFilter

    def get_filterset_kwargs(self, filterset_class)
        kwargs = super(ProductListView, self).get_filterset_kwargs(filterset_class)
        kwargs['attribute'] = 'width'
        return kwargs
```

In your `FilterSet` class, you can either pop the attribute from kwargs:

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        attribute = kwargs.pop['attribute']
        super(ProductFilter, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Or explicitly include it in the signature.

```
class ProductFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    def __init__(self, attribute=None, **kwargs):
        super(ProductFilter, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

Comment: How do i get attribute in `__init__` function? I tried this solution, but in `__init__` there is no attribute in kwargs.